# How to set the HTML attribute using an angular variable?

Tags: angularjs

```
  <div class="radio-inline" ng-repeat="customerOption in customerOptions">
       <input type="radio" name="customer" ng-change="getCustomers(customerType)" ng-model="customerType" ng-value="customerOption.Key" ng-checked="customerOption.Checked" />{{customerOption.Value}}
  </div>
```

This doesn't seem to do anything:

```
 ng-attr-id="{{customerOption.Value}}"
```

or:

```
 ng-attr-id="customerOption.Value"
```

or:

```
 id="customerOption.Value"
```

These puts exactly that line in the html

Comment: Why are you trying to set the id attribute anyway?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I am trying to pre-select one of the radio buttons.

Comment: I guess that you might have a good reason... try `ng-attr-id="{{customerOption.Value}}"` although there are few good reasons to do this.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I am trying to pre-select one of the radio buttons. -- you don't need an ID to do it, use ng-model that's hooked to the radio button

Comment: @maurycy how would I do that with the model?

Comment: you could try 
id="{{customerOption.value}}"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a quick plunker to show use of ng-model for default radio

http://plnkr.co/edit/F3M2fzLaYYrIwQdtuwHT?p=preview

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.gender = 'female';
});

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" ng-model="gender">Male
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female" ng-model="gender">Female
</body>
```

Comment: I am looping through the customerOptions array. How would I access the specific one that I want to set?

Comment: You only needs to set the model to correct value, i've in my example 2 values `[male, female]` so I've set `$scope.gener` which is a model for both radios to correct string value